# No space left on device error on juliabox

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

recently I do projects with JuliaBox However when I want to save a notebook I get the following error:

```
"Unexpected error while saving file: <path and name of the notebook> [Errno 28] No space left on device"
```

The same also happens when I simply open the notebook as soon as the auto-save kicks in.

I would be surprised if I really ran out of space since there's not too much stuff on my JuliaBox,(I did install a few packages and modules though).

1) Is there a way to check how much space I'm actually using?
2) Is anyone having similar issues? and how to solve it.

thanks!

Comment: click on the spanner on the top right it will show you your profile / disk-usage. I think you only get 500M free so could easily be that you have used that up...

Comment: That's strange but it shows this error `500: Internal Server Error`

Comment: cool thing. when I sign in with google account I get this error. when I sign in with my github account its ok!